# Number of divisors of composite number between and adjacent to twin primes

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, estimation, twin-primes

I am investigating properties of the number of divisors of composites between and adjacent to twin primes. When running some numeric calculations in Python (which are hopefully correct) I get the following result:
[image]

I want to somehow prove that this tendency is always true, meaning that the number between two twin primes tend to have more divisors than the ones adjacent to the twins.

This is my first attempt on doing something, hehe. Please tell me if this is at all true and if it somehow can be used to prove the suggested tenedency:

Prime numbers are always of the form $6k\pm 1$ except for the case when the prime is either $2$ or $3$. Let $p$ and $q$ be twin primes, and let $n$ be the number that lies between $p$ and $q$. If $p = 6k-1$, then $q = 6k+1$. Furthermore, we have that $n-2 = 6k-2$, $n = 6k$, and $n+2 = 6k+2$. Now, considering $n, n-1$ and $n+2$ under the $\tau (n)$ function, which represents the sum of divisors function, we have:

$\tau(n)=\tau(6k)\geq 4$ since $6k$ has at least the divisors $1, 2, 3$ and $6k$.
$\tau(6k−2)\geq 3$ since $6k-2$ has at least the divisors $1, 2$ and $6k-2$.

Similarly,
$\tau(6k+2)\geq 3$.

Therefore, we have that $\tau(n) - \tau(n-2) > 0$ and $\tau(n) - \tau(n+2) > 0$.

Given that the above holds true we can also conclude that $$\dfrac {\tau (n)}{\tau (n) + \tau (n-2) + \tau (n+2)} \geq \dfrac{4}{10}.$$

Comment: Since $6k$ is always divisible by three, $\tau(6k)$ is likely to exceed $\tau(6k\pm2)$. But it certainly isn't true that $\tau(n)-\tau(n-2)>0$ for all $n$ between twin primes. You know that from your data.

Comment: How can one then show that $\tau (6k)$ likely to exceed $\tau (6k \pm 2)$ for sufficiently large n? I agree, for instance $\tau (4)-\tau(6) = 3-4 =-1 < 0$

Comment: $\tau(6k)$ is guaranteed to be at least $6$, and at least $8$ for $k$ large enough. $\tau(6k\pm2)$ is only guaranteed to be at least $4$ for large $k$. That's a heuristic argument, not a proof, that $\tau(6k)$ is likely to exceed $\tau(6k\pm2)$. I suspect that someone who knows more Analytic Number Theory than I do could turn this into a rigorous proof.

Comment: @Victor Galeano : when $a \le 4$ and  $b\le 4+3+3$, you cannot conclude that \frac{a}{b} \le \frac{4}{10}, it is generally false.

Comment: You focus on numbers $n$ between 2 primes. This set is a subset of integers that can be divided by 6. I suggest that you do same analyze for all integers $n$ that can be divided by 6 : how many divisors for $n$, for $n-2$ and for $n+2$ ? I guess you will obtain very similar results.

Comment: One thing that is going to make it difficult to answer the question is that we have no proof that there are infinitely many twin primes, so how are we going to get any density estimates as $k\to\infty$? May be better to focus on the variant @Lou suggests, which may be more amenable to solution.

Comment: And if we are interested with twin-prime, it is interesting to see if the density if different for numbers like $6k$ that are between 2 primes, and other numbers that are like $6k$.

Comment: Thanks everyone! We'll see if I go further into this, but for those who are interested I found this article http://bit-player.org/2021/does-having-prime-neighbors-make-you-more-composite where the author in question looks into alot of the things that you have been suggesting